# Generating training data using Tess4J

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

I am using [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/) to use [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) programmatically, which works great for recognition tasks.

Now I want to add some features that help with generating traineddata files from texts like described in [this wiki article](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3), but from Java/Tess4J. It won't matter if I have to use the "NEW Automated method" or the "Old Manual method". Both will be fine.

Does Tess4J support this or is there another binding for Java that is capable of training Tesseract?

Comment: The article you mention talks about using additional libraries, the "training" libraries. Tess4J is really just a wrapper around JNA 4.0, the Java Native Access code. So, it seems to me if you want to use the additional libraries you are going to have to write JNA code for those libraries. If you do, it would make a great open-source project. You might find some opensource projects that have done this, but I haven't looked.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether those other executables are part of libtesseract302.(dll|so) or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The training is provided by other executables besides Tesseract, and they are not exposed as API or libraries. For Java-based Tesseract training, you may want to check out [jTessBoxEditor](http://vietocr.sf.net/training.html) project.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I think I'll have to investigate in how to write a JNA wrapper for the training tools. Probably I can build a library that exposes that functionality.

Comment: I'll accept this as the solution for now until there is a better one.

Comment: @nguyenq, the aboe project doesn't support arabic, are there any projects that supports arabic ?

Comment: @MahmoudS, try the new jTessBoxEditorFX tool.